# Swift - Dark background of the ViewController that appears over the context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Here is the code that creates my custom popUp:

```
extension UIViewController {

    public func presentPopup(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        let popup = MBPopUpViewController(accentColor: UIColor(hexString: "E40C15"),
                                          popUpTitle: "Hello",
                                          popUpMessage: "Test PopUp",
                                          popUpFirstButtonLabel: "1",
                                          popUpSecondButtonLabel: "2")

        popup.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(popup, animated: animated, completion: completion)

    }

}
```

Is there a way, how to make the first view controller a bit darker with fade animation, when the second appears?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V0VVpSNwxQAd2W4YZfNGuMyD3ZL9yl6b) you can see what I have now.

You can see an example [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EuckSZKAoS55pf_B821cw5U3I4dXfbdC), in photos app. When the AlertViewController appears, the background becomes darker. Are there any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks :)

Comment: Please make your images public, we are not able to see your google drive files.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the links :D

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want a `Modal Popover`.

It is possible to make the background color of the view being placed over another a transparent color. You will need to set the color and everything for that view in it's `viewDidLoad`.

Ensure that the segue is marked `Cover Vertical` that so there's no wipe animation, and it's a smooth fade. Also enable either `Over Current Context` or `Over Full Screen` depending on how you would like this to look.

The end result will look something like below depending on what elements you place in your second View Controller that you are segueing to. (**NOTE:** the animation displayed in the gif is sped up. And the dark grey area would contain whatever it is that you place in the view).

There's some great resources out there to help you with making these.  I can recommend [Mark Moeykens](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChH6WbyYeX0INJjrK2-6WSg) on YouTube, he makes great videos about things like this.

[image]

Comment: I think, it will not suit me. I want the default view controller animation as I have a custom class for popOver that should slide from the bottom, all I need is animation for the dark background. Here is what I have now: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V0VVpSNwxQAd2W4YZfNGuMyD3ZL9yl6b

Comment: Just updated my question with the code that I use to create the object of my custom popUp class

Comment: This is still possible, and is still what I would reccomend in doing this. Just change the modal transition style from `Cross Dissolve` to `Cover Vertical`

Comment: Ahahah, the fact is that I need to set cover vertical for the popUp and crossDissolve for the black background: PopUp should slide from the bottom to its original position and the background should change its Alpha from 0 to 0.2 without any movement :) It it possible?

Comment: You may end up having to create a custom transition style then, since there's nothing default that does both of those at the same time.

Comment: Got it, I will try to make my own transition :( Thanks!